# UPnP ContentDirectory Browse returns null

Tags: java, upnp

I have been playing around with UPnP, to get an understanding of how it all works, before I try working with any of the APIs that are out there, or doing anything more substantial. I have been reading through the UPnP documentation, and have used that information to format the messages that I am sending. I am just working from the command line right now, and have gotten discovery messages to work without issue. Now, I'm trying to return content from a ContentDirectory Browse() request (I have also tried TransportAV GetMediaInfo() because it takes only one argument). However, no matter what I try, I am getting a Null response from the MediaServer.

```
public class SOAPSocket2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + 
                "<s:Envelope " +
                    "xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ \"" +
                    "s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">" +
                "<s:Body>" +
                    "<u:GetMediaInfo xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1\">" +
                        "<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>" +
                    "</u:GetMediaInfo>" +
                "</s:Body>" +
                "</s:Envelope>";

        //Create socket
        String hostname = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        Socket sock = new Socket(hostname, port);

        //Send header
        String path = args[2];
        BufferedWriter  wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        // You can use "UTF8" for compatibility with the Microsoft virtual machine.
        wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        wr.write("HOST: " + hostname + ":" + port +"\r\n");
        wr.write("CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
        wr.write("SOAPACTION: \"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#GetMediaInfo\"");
        wr.write("\r\n");

        //Send data
        wr.write(xmldata);
        wr.flush();

        // Response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        line = rd.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I know this isn't the most proper code, but I borrowed it from here: http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/xmlpost.htm. I figured that if I could actually get some sort of data in a response, then I could work on building it properly. I have modified it so that I pass the IP address and Port of the Media Server from the command line, as well as the path to the Control URL. However, I am getting nothing but 'null' from the Media Server. Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting a Null response from the MediaServer

Is that a response from MediaServer? I would imagine it's just BufferedReader telling you there's nothing to return.

You have two things here you can debug (sending and receiving) but the same tools should help with both. Use wireshark or another network traffic capture tool to see the actual data that goes through the network. Wireshark will tell you if the response is sent (but you are failing to receive it properly) or if the reply never comes (implying your message is incorrect). It will also show your message as it is on the wire, making it easier to notice mistakes.

Doing the above (and pasting the messages here if you can't figure it out) is the best way to continue debugging, but I can see some problems in the code already:

- SOAPACTION-line is missing "\r\n" in the end
- There is no CONTENT-LENGTH header (this is required in normal cases)

These aren't even UPnP problems really, the message just isn't proper HTTP. Still, the [UPnP Device Architecture](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) document will help with problems like this.

Comment: thank you for your input. I did notice that the \r\n was missing, and I have been looking at the Device Architecture since starting this project. I also used Wireshark extensively, but could not find the source of my problem prior to posting here. However, I did finally get a second device that I could use as a control point, and monitored the traffic between them. I noticed that the packets containing the SOAP were identified as HTTP, but mine were not. Changing from a BufferedWriter to a PrintWriter ultimately fixed the issue. Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: Also the CONTENT-LENGTH line. I overlooked that